# How do I fix the following error in the context of running Neo4j's louvain algorithm: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1?

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

EDIT: This was not working because it was a bipartite graph.  I have to make a projection first.  I will update after I solve it. Please feel free to still comment/answer.

When I run the below code in Neo4 desktop, I get the following error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.louvain`: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

I understand I may have an index mismatch between the PATIENT nodes and the HAS_PRESCRIPTIONS relationship.  Not every patient has prescriptions, for example.  How do I get Neo4j to ignore this error or how do I fix it?

For context, other algorithms such as the algo.scc procedure worked on the same set of nodes and relationships. I should add that I do have constraints forcing the PATIENT and PRESCRIPTION nodes to be distinct.

```
CALL algo.louvain('PATIENTS', 'HAS_PRESCRIPTION',
    {write:true, writeProperty:'community'})
YIELD nodes, communityCount, iterations, loadMillis, computeMillis, 
writeMillis;
```

I would expect the algo.louvain procedure to at least compile, and return the nodes, communityCount, iterations, loadMillis, computeMilis, writeMillis.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that since this is a bipartite graph, with patient nodes only connected to prescription nodes, I had to induce a patient-patient graph like this:

```
CALL algo.louvain.stream(
     'MATCH (i:PRESCRIPTION) RETURN id(i) as id',
     'MATCH (i1:PRESCRIPTION)<--(:PATIENTS)-->(i2:PRESCRIPTION)
  WITH i1,i2,count(*) as common_patients
  WHERE common_patients > 20
  RETURN id(i1) as source,id(i2) as target, common_patients as weight'
     ,{graph:'cypher'}) yield nodeId, community
MATCH (p:PRESCRIPTION) where id(p)=nodeId
RETURN  community,
    count(*) as communitySize,
    collect(p.SHORT_TITLE) as ps
ORDER BY communitySize desc limit 5
```

This came from the following source: https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/2017/11/27/neo4j-graph-algorithms-projecting-a-virtual-graph/